# Обратиться к массиву php

Tags: php, массивы

После парсинга поста вк возвращается массив вложений вида

```
( [0] => Array ( [type] => photo [photo] => Array ( [pid] => 
456487 [aid] => -7 [owner_id] => -13062 [user_id] => 100 [src] => 
https://pp.vk.me/c637127/v637127065/cb18/3NHf4.jpg [src_big] => 
https://pp.vk.me/c637127/v637127065/cb19/997p8.jpg [src_small] => 
https://pp.vk.me/c637127/v637127065/cb17/GBnNE.jpg [src_xbig] => 
https://pp.vk.me/c637127/v637127065/cb1a/pEHQ.jpg [src_xxbig] => 
https://pp.vk.me/c637127/v637127065/cb1b/En753s.jpg [width] => 
1200 [height] => 800 [text] => [created] => 1470723 [post_id] => 
597 [access_key] => 5674fed5bad8 ) ) )
```

Как вообще извлечь значение допустим [src_xbig]?

Comment: А как этот массив называется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно,

```
 $имя_массива[0]['photo']['src_xbig']
```

, не?